# Conjugation in finite simple classical groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G_n(q)=\mathrm{(P)SL}_n(q), \mathrm{(P)SU}_n(q),\mathrm{(P)Sp}_{2n}(q)$, $\Omega_{2n+1}(q), (P)\Omega^\pm_{2n}(q)$ be a simple classical group. Consider the natural embedding $G_{n-1}(q) \subset G_n(q)$ if there is such. I would appreciate very much if you have an argument or a counterexample for the following:

Claim: If $x,y\in G_{n-1}(q)$ such that $x^T=y$ for some $T\in \mathrm{Aut}(G_n(q))$, then there exists $t\in \mathrm{Aut}(G_{n-1}(q))$ such that $x^t=y$.

P/S: I have modified the question slightly based on Nick's comment.

Comment: You should be a little careful: if I'm thinking correctly, $PSL_{n-1}(q)$ doesn't always embed naturally in $PSL_n(q)$, sometimes one ends up with a cover. For instance you won't get $PSL_3(4)$ as a subgroup of $PSL_4(4)$ in this way. Perhaps you'd be better of stating the question in terms of $SL_{n-1}(q)$ inside $SL_n(q)$?

Comment: (Just a comment: does not answer the question) Let $q$ be a prime power equal to 3 mod 4. Then in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(q)$ the images of the matrices $M_{\pm}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \pm 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ are not conjugate, but the images of the matrices $M_\pm\oplus I_1$ are conjugate in $\mathrm{PSL}_3(q)$ (the matrices $M_\pm\oplus I_1$ are conjugate in $\mathrm{SL}_3(q)$).

Comment: @YCor, I think this is covered by the fact that we can choose $t$ in $Aut(G_{n-1}(q))$ rather than just in $G_{n-1}(q)$??

Comment: @NickGill indeed I misread the question, thanks. Amending my comment...!

Comment: The claim is certainly true if $x$ and $y$ have a 1-eigenspace of dimension $1$...

Comment: I think for $SL_n(q)$ then this statement is true if $T\in GL_{n-1}(q)$, since the conjugacy classes are given by Jordan rational form. I'd have to do some doodling to make sure of this. One then has to attend to field, and to graph automorphisms and my sense is that this would carry through OK. I'd probably have a look at the book of Burness and Giudici to see how far I could take this approach.

Comment: Steve, why don't you amend the question to take Nick Gill's first comment into account?

Answer (score 1):

[Again misread the question... sorry. Leaving the answer for context.]

A bit sketchy, but I guess it can be filled.

Consider $\mathrm{SO}(8)$, with respect with the quadratic form $J_8$ given by the antidiagonal matrix. A Cartan subalgebra consists of the matrices $\mathrm{diag}(x,y,z,t,-t,-z,-y,-x)$. Choose these coordinates, for which the Killing form on the Cartan subalgebra is proportional to the usual scalar product. Then (up to a single scalar), the simple coroots (for the positivity corresponding to upper triangular matrices) are $\alpha_1=(0,1,-1,0)$, $\alpha_2=(1,-1,0,0)$, $\alpha_3=(0,0,1,-1)$, and $\alpha_4=(0,0,1,1)$. The last three are pairwise orthogonal, and triality permutes them arbitrarily. In particular, some automorphism maps $\alpha_2+\alpha_3=(1,-1,1,-1)$ to $\alpha_3+\alpha_4=(0,0,2,0)$. That is, at a group level, it maps $\mathrm{diag}(t,t^{-1},t,t^{-1},t,t^{-1},t,t^{-1})$ to $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,t^2,1,1,t^{-2},1,1)$. For $t\neq \pm 1$, these are not linearly conjugate (even in $\mathrm{PSO}_8$).

Based on this, I believe that for $t\neq\pm 1$ in any finite field $K$ of odd cardinal, except maybe a few exceptions, that $\mathrm{diag}(t,t^{-1},t,t^{-1},t,t^{-1},t,t^{-1})$ (which modulo scalar is $\mathrm{diag}(t^2,1,t^2,1,t^2,1,t^2,1)$) and $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,t^2,1,1,t^{-2},1,1)$ are conjugate (by an automorphism) in $\mathrm{PSO}_8(K)$, but are not conjugate (by any automorphism) in a larger $\mathrm{SO}_n$ (with respect to a form $J_8\oplus J_{n-8}$), since for $n\ge 9$ the automorphisms should come from $\mathrm{O}_n$ and field automorphisms.

Note: An easier non-Lie analogue (of this phenomenon, where the question is reversed): 3-cycles and double 3-cycles are automophism-conjugate in $\mathrm{Alt}_6$, but not in $\mathrm{Alt}_n$ for $n\ge 7$.